# Triggering Prometheus scrape manually

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to trigger Prometheus scrape ?
i.e. either from the Prometheus web UI or using some other command line utility ?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus scrape is built to use polling according to your interval configuration.

In some cases you might need to send the metrics in a specific time in point, thus Prometheus provides the [Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/)

Just be aware of the [drawbacks when using Pushgateway and when to use it.](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing)

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus doesn't provide the ability for manually triggered scrape. But such an ability is provided by [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) - lightweight Prometheus-compatible scraper I work on. It provides the `response` link per each scrape target at `http://vmagent:8429/targets` page. Click on the `response` link in order to trigger the scrape on `vmagent` behalf to the given target. The link returns plain response from the given scrape target. Note that `vmagent` doesn't store metrics obtained via manual scrape.